# Does csrf protection is required in django api?

Tags: django, csrf

Im currently making an app with flutter, and to communicate with mysql server using django for restAPI. Also Im using session for protection. In this case d I also need to use CSRF protection? If I plan to build an website with flutter in the future, does CSRF Protection is required?